# Listview: Headers and custom layout rows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-xml

In Android, I have a listview that uses a custom adapter to change the look of each row of the listview. However, I need to find a way to use and adapter to be able to multiple different layouts for specific squares. I would also like to be able to use Headers which I have never used. I would like it to look something like this layout here:

[image: Snap Android App Preferences Layout]

How can I best do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView is use for layout which contains a list of objects which the same layout for each row. In your case I think you should design a layout exactly what you want, do not use ListView.

Comment: Thanks! I took your advice and made a custom view with a vertical ScrollView

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use listview here. but if you want to use listview with different row layouts, do like this in your adapter:

```
private static final int ROW_TYPE1 = 0;
private static final int ROW_TYPE2 = 1;
private static final int ROW_TYPE3 = 2;
int type;
```

and

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
if (position == 0)
    type = ROW_TYPE1;
else if (position == 1)
    type = ROW_TYPE2;
else
    type = ROW_TYPE3;
return type;
}

@Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3; 
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
int type = getItemViewType(position);
if (convertView  == null)
switch (type) {
    case ROW_TYPE1:
        // inflate layout1
        break;
    case ROW_TYPE2:
        // inflate layout2
        break;
    case ROW_TYPE3:
        // inflate layout3
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```